# Prestashop 1.7 check available stock at final order step

Tags: prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.7

I had something working on Prestashop 1.6 to check cart quantities before the customer can buy. Here is my problem on Prestashop 1.7 :
If a customer put an item in his cart today, he comes back in 2 days and he is still logged in. The cart is still available while the product, in reality, became out of stock.
The customer can make the order and the quantity in my stock is -1. Since I upgraded to prestashop 1.7 it's a disaster, I have quantities at -5, -10...because if this non-checked scenario.

```
abstract class PaymentModule extends PaymentModuleCore
{
    public function validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method = 'Unknown',
        $message = null, $extra_vars = array(), $currency_special = null, $dont_touch_amount = false,
        $secure_key = false, Shop $shop = null)
    {

        if (!isset($this->context))
            $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $this->context->cart = new Cart($id_cart);

        if (!$this->context->cart->checkQuantities()){
            Tools::redirect(__PS_BASE_URI__.'order.php?step=0');
        }
        return parent::validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method, $message, 
            $extra_vars, $currency_special, $dont_touch_amount, $secure_key, $shop);
    }
}
```

Comment: With 1.7 the quantity after check out is wrong?

Comment: No, the issue I'm facing is the cart isn't checked between when you add something in your cart and the checkout. Due to this, a 2 days old pending cart can be ordered while the items aren't still available. Then you got an under zero amount in your item stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the best solution is to use this addons : https://addons.prestashop.com/en/stock-supplier-management/21707-temporary-product-reservation-lonely-stock.html

Prestashop handles really bad cart stocks.

Anyway if you want to do it yourself and check stock available it's pretty simple :

```
<?php

    $cart = $this->context->cart;
    $cart_products = $cart->getProducts();

    if (!empty($cart_products)) {

        $db = Db::getInstance();

        foreach ($cart_products as $key => $cart_product) {

            $real_quantity = StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct($cart_product['id_product'], $cart_product['id_product_attribute']);

            if ( (int) $real_quantity < (int) $cart_product['quantity'] ) {

                // If negative
                $real_quantity = (int) $real_quantity < 0 ? 0 : $real_quantity;

                $sql = '
                        UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_product`
                        SET quantity = '.(int) $real_quantity.',`date_add` = NOW()
                        WHERE `id_product` = '.(int) $cart_product['id_product'].
                        (!empty($cart_product['id_product_attribute']) ? ' AND `id_product_attribute` = '.(int) $cart_product['id_product_attribute'] : '').'
                        AND `id_cart` = '.(int) $cart->id;

                    $db->execute($sql);
            }

        }

        // Garbage collector
        $db->execute('DELETE FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_product WHERE quantity < 1 ');

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Matt Loye for this code but, could you tell me where I have to put this code to the cart be checked after you click on checkout ? I mean when you see the sum up of your cart.

Comment: You have to create a module (see generator here : https://validator.prestashop.com/generator , you need to create an account first) with the right hook. Your checkout process will certainly have displayAfterShoppingCartBlock where you can execute this code.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Just one more thing, actually it redirect the customer to the webiste index. Could you tell me please where, in the code, can I add a redirect to a preferred location ? I will add as settings option created CMS pages to select a CMS page saying to the customer what just happened.

Comment: Please open another ticket and mark this one as resolved to keep things in order here ;) it's another subject.

Comment: Caution: That addon is not recommended for websites with a lot of traffic. The perfomance will decrease drastically. The addon use the database in a very aggressive way...